# How to Delete Using Join EXASol

Tags: sql, database, exasolution

I want to delete some records from a table using Join in EXAsol.

I am trying -

```
Delete tran
FROM 
Transactions tran
INNER JOIN 
Employees e
ON tran.ID = e.Transaction_ID
WHERE e.Name = 'Abhisar';
```

The error I am getting is -

```
syntax error, unexpected identifier_chain2, expecting FROM_ or '*' [line 1,column 8]
```

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about exasolution (first time I even noticed that tag).  But I wouldn't expect to see a Transaction_ID in an Employees table?  Wouldn't it be more something like `JOIN Employees e ON t.emp_id = e.emp_id`? Btw, I don't know, but maybe `tran` could be a reserved word in exasolution? Like some abbreviation for `transaction`?

Comment: @LukStorms Select * works, so join is not an issue. Also, changed abbreviation from tran to a bunch of other words. Still the same issue.

Comment: I don't know anything about the SQL syntax it uses. But perhaps using an IN instead? F.e. `DELETE * FROM Transactions WHERE ID IN (SELECT Transaction_ID FROM Employees WHERE Name = 'Abhisar')`
`

Comment: @LukStorms This statement would work perfectly fine in SQL. It's just Exasol (which is basically SQL) in which im facing this problem. Nevermind, I'll just wait for an answer.

Comment: What about the ANSI SQL compliant `DELETE FROM Transactions WHERE ID IN (SELECT Transaction_ID FROM Employees WHERE Name = 'Abhisar')`? (I.e. LukStorm's suggestion, but without `*`.)

Comment: @jarlh Yes, this can be done. But, would be much slower than a join functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tab1 a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab2 b WHERE a.id=b.id);
```

This is as good as JOIN and uses index internally. You may verify it if you enable profiling and check it after query execution.

Answer (score 0):

The original error message is due to the 'TRAN' immediately following the 'DELETE' - see the Exasol user manual - the only valid ANSI SQL options for DELETE are 'DELETE FROM..' or 'DELETE * FROM...'

There are then various options as described above to pick the records which are to be deleted. Personally I tend to use the 'WHERE .. IN..(SELECT...)' method as I think this is clearer and therefore easier to maintain.